# How to design class that I need use derived class member in base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, combinations, virtual-functions, class-design

Generally, we use virtual-function or composition to design class.As I know, use virtual-function will make class more structured; use composition will be easy to impl, but maybe write more duplicate code.
In this situation: I need a parser, it will use for different protocol.Now, I suppose that it will use in A-Protocol named AParser, B-Protocol named BParser, like the follow:

```cpp
class Parser {
 public:
  Parser(...);
  virtual ~Parser() = default;
  virtual bool Parse(...) = 0;

 private:
  // some attributes may be common
};

class AParser() : public Parser {
 public:
  AParser(...) : Parser() {};
  ~AParser() override = default;

  void bool Parser(...) override;
  inline AData Data() const { return AData_;}

 private:
  AData_;
}

class BParser() : public Parser {
 public:
  BParser(...) : Parser() {};
  ~BParser() override = default;

  void bool Parser(...) override;
  inline BData Data() const { return BData_;}

 private:
  BData_;
}
```

well, `AData` and `BData` both are their own private data, shouldn't put into base class,

also, shouldn't `virtual AData/BData Data() = 0`   (WRONG! ! !)

So, how to design the class to solve the problem?
Now I have two ideas, but I think they can't satisfied me

1. use `static_cast<derived_class>(this)->derivedFunc()`, first this operation isn't elegant, second if I use this operation, is `Inheritance + encapsulation` still meaningful?
2. use common function, like `virtual std::map<std::string, void *> GetData() = 0`, then use `member field name` to get the filed data, but how to use derived fucntions is still  a problem?

I think this question may be a class design question, could you please help me answer the question?

Comment: What is the point of this `GetData()` function? Why can't you just use your parsers via their baseclass interface? Are you perhaps missing `GetData()` in the baseclass interface?

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking for. Even so your description is unclear. Example: "virtual-function or combination" What is "combination". A combination of what? Please do less description of all the background and focus on the programming related things. BTW: "inline" keyword is obscure in this context!

Comment: No, I can't. Becasue A B is different protocol, can't design a  `GetData()`, they return different type, different type has their own fileds. And I have another question: how to use derived class function in base class ptr/ref, if the function can't be designed as virtual function

Comment: Do you need to call `getData` from a `Parser &`? Can the thing that needs `AData` use `AParser`, and the thing that needs `BData` instead use `BParser`, and the things that don't care not call it?

Comment: @Klaus I'm asking for how to design the class in this situation, are you clear now? `combination` ,sorry, I mean `composition`, it can also complete the target, but  may write      more duplicate code, I want to know how to achieve the target use Inheritance. why I describe so much background? becasue so much related question's answer is " to define virtual function in base class" I think the specific issues require specific background, don't you think so?

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I understand what you mean. First, `GetData()` is an example, means get A's data or B's data, to describe the question I met.Second, We can use AParser when need AData, use BParser when BData. But better than this use `composition`, no need to use  Inheritance, the  Inheritance is no meaningful, thx

Comment: Question is not clear. We have no idea how you are planning to use this interface, so how can we possibly tell you how to design it? I also agree with Klaus. All the descriptions are just confusing, and there is to little code showing what you actually want/need.

Comment: @super Sorry to describe question so confusing, but as @Sebastian said, this question is a design question, if these two class functions can't return the same type data, shouldn't have a common base class. if they still have a common class, use `static_cast` to derived class is type unsafe, use `dynamic_cast` to derived class is harmful, and I should use virtual funtion to avoid use RTTI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two parsers don't return the same data, they do not have a related interface and probably shouldn't have a common base class.

If they do return the same data, put the `GetData` function in the base class. Or better yet, return the data directly from `Parse`.